# How to invoke application after coming back on home Screen in Android?

Tags: android

I am new in Android . I need a little help.

I have created a sample chat application using socket. After launching application.

I am on the my application Activity. After some time I am back to Home Screen . And If

some times back some info or message come from my Server side How to invoke my chat application or How to inform the my application so that it relaunches..

Any idea please suggest me.

Thanks in Advance

Anshu

Comment: you are coming to ur app.'s home screen or device's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you alwayshave 2 keep the background thread running.

Then u will have to listen to broadcast Messages.,

After recieving broadcast msg. in onRecieve() Method you can do wat u want.

[Look at this link.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)

Comment: This is not my Problem , I want On ignoring after doing some thing in Application , How to resume previour running Application like radio or mediaplayer or Browser .